# Can't install Pillow on centos

Tags: python, setuptools, python-2.6, python-imaging-library

I have cenots 6.3 and python 2.6 on it when I try to install it via easyinstall I get following error:

```
_imaging.c:76:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /tmp/easy_install-HY7WI1/Pillow-2.3.0/libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                 from _imaging.c:82:
/tmp/easy_install-HY7WI1/Pillow-2.3.0/libImaging/ImPlatform.h:14:2: error: #error Sorry, this library requires support for ANSI prototypes.
/tmp/easy_install-HY7WI1/Pillow-2.3.0/libImaging/ImPlatform.h:17:2: error: #error Sorry, this library requires ANSI header files.
/tmp/easy_install-HY7WI1/Pillow-2.3.0/libImaging/ImPlatform.h:55:2: error: #error Cannot find required 32-bit integer type
In file included from _imaging.c:82:
/tmp/easy_install-HY7WI1/Pillow-2.3.0/libImaging/Imaging.h:93: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘INT32’
/tmp/easy_install-HY7WI1/Pillow-2.3.0/libImaging/Imaging.h:400: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ImagingCRC32’
......................
_imaging.c:3409: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

by the way, my gcc compiler is 4.4.7, if that helps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to install `python26-devel` before you can compile *any* Python extension.

To compile Pillow, you'll also need to install the development headers for various other libraries, including `libjpeg-devel` and `zlib-devel`. See the [Pillow installation instructions](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) for more details on what external libraries are needed.

Instead of a version-specific package, you can also install `python-devel`; you’ll get the right version for your distribution.

Comment: @MarkPeschel the question here was for Python2.6. Obviously for different Python versions a different, version-specific package is needed. `python-devel` and `python3-devel` get you the version you need for your distro.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure run this first:
`sudo yum install python-devel libjpeg-devel zlib-devel`

Comment: I also had to do `sudo yum install gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who come here for current solution (centos 7 with python 2.7.5), you will need **python-devel.x86_64** instead of **python26-devel**