# Can't install Pillow in Fedora23

Tags: python, django, pip, python-imaging-library

```
    (.newenv)[max@cyber life_besto]$ sudo pip install git+https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git
  Cloning https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git to /tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Found existing installation: Pillow 3.0.0
    Uninstalling Pillow-3.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled Pillow-3.0.0
  Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BMRc40-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    _____There are some codes_____
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Bands.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Bands.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Draw.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Draw.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/GifEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifEncode.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Filter.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Filter.o
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/LzwDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/LzwDecode.o
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Offset.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Offset.o
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Quant.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Quant.ogcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/RawEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawEncode.o
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/UnpackYCC.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/ZipEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/BoxBlur.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/encode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/map.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/display.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/outline.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/path.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crc32.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/LzwDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/MspDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Incremental.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantPngQuant.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64 -ljpeg -lz -ltiff -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL/_imaging.so
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/encode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/map.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/display.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/outline.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/path.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Access.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Resample.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Bands.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BitDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Blend.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Chops.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Convert.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Copy.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crc32.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crop.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Dib.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Draw.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Effects.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/EpsEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/File.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Fill.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Filter.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/FliDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Geometry.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GetBBox.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/HexDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Histo.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/LzwDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Matrix.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ModeFilter.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/MspDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Negative.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Offset.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Pack.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PackDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Palette.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Paste.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantOctree.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantHash.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantHeap.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcdDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcxDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcxEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Point.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RankFilter.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Storage.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Unpack.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TiffDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Incremental.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantPngQuant.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of Pillow
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BMRc40-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-zSgmXr-build/
```

I also tried to install using **pip install Pillow**, but it didn't help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `python-devel` as well as `redhat-rpm-config` packages first (see how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230444/how-to-install-python-developer-package)), then `pip install Pillow`.

More info on manual installation (as opposed to installing native OS packages like `python-imaging`) you'll find in [official installation guide](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: In my system , it's already installed :) But whatever it returns error

Comment: @A'zamMamatmurodov then check out [official installation docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) to ensure no other important libraries are missing. Also, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945610/cant-install-pillow-on-centos)

Comment: Yeah , thanks @vrs , i solved , i have just install libraries in the following code "sudo dnf install python-devel redhat-rpm-config" , it helped me ,

Comment: @A'zamMamatmurodov glad it worked! I've updated my answer, based on these comments. So, please, mark my answer as accepted, so other people will know it helped.